# How to find approximation and detail coefficient from a reconstructed signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, dwt

I want to decompose a signal and by reconstructing this signal try to find approximation and detail coefficient from the reconstructed signal. For decomposition I used single level decomposition(Discrete Wavelet Transform-Db6) and for reconstruction I used inverse discrete wavelet transform. But using `idwt` I have found only approximation coefficient. But I want to find detail coefficient from reconstructed signal. How can i do this?

```
ss=load('Fah_2-L05.mat');
[cA1,cD1] = dwt(ss.data,'db6');
[cA2,cD2] = dwt(cA1,'db6');
[cA3,cD3] = dwt(cA2,'db6');
[cA4,cD4] = dwt(cA3,'db6');
[cA5,cD5] = dwt(cA4,'db6');
[cA6,cD6] = dwt(cA5,'db6');
[cA7,cD7] = dwt(cA6,'db6');
[cA8,cD8] = dwt(cA7,'db6');
A8 = idwt(cA8,cD8,'db6'); %approximation coefficient of level 8
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. However, you have decomposed `cA7` into `[cA8,cD8]`. Then, you have synthesized  `[cA8,cD8]` back into `cA7` (weirdly named `A8` in your case). In the same way you can continue to next sub-bands.